# Ruby has_many model association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model-associations

Here is two table `properties` and `property_images` I want to associate both table.

**properties**

```
id
name
status
other-columns-here
```

**property_images**

```
id
property_id
image
status
```

Here is code -

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :property_images, dependent: :destroy
end


class PropertyImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def index
   @properties = Property.order('id');
   render html:@properties #13 properties coming
end
```

I have tried to `has_many` association but only coming `properties` data. Please help me

Comment: Do u want to include property image with each property?

Comment: Yes I want to include each property in has_many association

Comment: What you're actually asking is not clear in English.  I mean no offense (my wife is foreign, very familiar with this issue :) but perhaps try to reword the question.  Your code above successfully "associates" the two tables.  I would question why the index in your "users" controller is showing properties.  Perhaps you need to use nested attributes?  How are you loading Property and PropertyImage data?

Comment: @Chinu if any answer helped you please mark it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two models are correctly associated, however, if you want to access the property_images without making any extra queries in the view, you can do so by the following three methods:

```
@properties = Property.includes(:property_images)

@properties = Property.eager_load(:property_images)

@properties = Property.preload(:property_images)
```

You can read more about eagerloading/preloading in the following [blog](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/)

You can also add a scope to your property model, to access them more easily (and save a little bit of your time by not repeating the same code over and over again).

In your property model add the following

```
scope :with_property_images,-> {joins(:property_images)}
```

Then you can access properties with preloaded images by calling said scope.

**Update:** If you're using rails 4, the scope must be wrapped inside a lambda. I've updated the scope code, it should work on both rails 3 and 4.

Comment: While I am render `properties` the `property_images` records not coming

Comment: Could you post the current code you're using and the output (@properties.inspect) please.

Comment: render html: @properties.inspect

Comment: And how are you calling with_property_images scope?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109924/discussion-between-chinu-and-waclock).

Answer (score 1):

Try this controller

```
# controller.rb
def index
   @properties = Property.includes(:property_images)
end
```

and view

```
#view.html.erb
<% @properties.each do |p| %>
   <% p.property_images.each do |image| %>
      <%= image.id %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to  use :include => :property_images to eager load when you query for properties

You would put this in the params for the query. May just need to use Property.find

Comment: Where I will use`:include => :property_images` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
def index
   @properties = Property.includes(:property_images).order('id');
   #render html:@properties #13 properties coming
end
```

For viewing images:

```
 <% @properties.each do |p| %>
   <% p.each do |image| %>
      view image & data
   <% end %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: `<% p.each do |image| %>
      view image & data
   <% end %> ` not working.

Comment: undefined method `each' for #<Property:0x765f330>

Answer (score 0):

try the following controller and view

```
# users_controller.rb
def index
   @properties = Property.includes(:property_images).order(:id)
end
```

In your view, you need to put each for property_images not property,

```
#properties.html.erb
<% @properties.each do |p| %>
   <% p.property_images.each do |image| %>
      <%= image.id %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```